# how can I plot a histogram using random.expovariate() PYTHON

Tags: python, random, statistics

I have a question where it shows customers entering a bar at a rate of 7 per hour, the question states i NEED to use random.expovariate() and generate a histogram showing 100 inter-arrival times. 
So far i have this

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random

def customers():    
    x=np.random.expovariate(7,100)                                                                                                                                
    plt.hist(x,100)
    plt.axis([-0,100,0,100])
    plt.show()
    return True

def main():
    global history
    print(customers()) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I am getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'expovariate'
```

Also i am not 100% this is how i would show the graph, i have researched it and not found a clear answer anywhere!
Hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to get you started:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random

def customers():
    x = [random.expovariate(7) for r in xrange(100)]                   
    plt.hist(x,10)
    plt.show()
    return True

def main():
    global history
    print(customers()) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Your main issues were:

1. you were calling `np.random.expovariate()` rather than `random.expovariate()`
2. `random.expovariate()` takes 1 argument rather than 2
3. `random.expovariate()` only produces one number, to create a histogram you need more than one.  In the above I created a list of expovariate random numbers.

Comment: Thanks! just to compare how would you do the same question but using Poisson distribution?

Comment: a simple search for `python poisson` led me [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html).  Seek and you will find!